# How to catchError in a StreamProvider in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an issue with StreamProvider as i try to fetch non existing data in firestore.

```
Stream<CollectedItem> streamCollectedItem(String id,int category)
{
      return _db
          .collection('users')
          .document(id)
          .collection('CollectedItems').where('category', isEqualTo: category)
          .limit(1)
          .snapshots()
          .map((snap) => CollectedItem.fromFirestore(snap.documents.first));

    }
```

and i'm calling this function like this :

```
return StreamProvider<CollectedItem>.value(
     value: db.streamCollectedItem(userID,collectMeNotification.category),
          child: AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Quantité'),
            content: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: popUp(collectMeNotification,userID)

              ),
```

But i'm getting a "no catchError was provided" problem because i'm linking my stream with a non existing data.

How can i fix this ?

Comment: It looks like your stream is throwing. Is it expected?

Comment: The problem is my stream is not returning null when there is no element in firestore, it's returning an exception

Comment: You want it to return null then?

Comment: yeaaah, i want it to return null if there is no data with this query in firestore

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `catchError` to provide a fallback value in case the stream emits an error.

To emit `null` for example, this would be:

```dart
StreamProvider(
  builder: (_) => someStream,
  catchError: (_, __) => null,
  child: ...,
)
```